# What is the right end-to-end process for transmitting/computing w/ HIPPA-compliant data?

Tags: encryption, mobile

Not a security expert so please excuse what may be a basic question. I am creating a health app that needs to be HIPPA compliant. I will of course hire a consultant later on, but I need a feel for how this system would/could work.

Think about something like FitBit, which harvests health data, may perform a computation and then send it back to a user's device.

Here is what I have so far as a possible means of transmitting PHI data from the client (or a mobile device) to the cloud, performing computations on this data (e.g. drawing some conclusions about this data compared to other data sets), and then sending back data to the device.

**However, I need clarification on where and when the encryption should take place to conform to regulations.**

1. PHI sensitive data is gathered on locally, on the device (client-side).
2. This data is sent to a private server where it is tokenised (remote token service server) – or it is somehow encrypted on the device.
3. Computations on this tokenized data occur in the cloud.
4. Anonymised or tokenized data is stored in the cloud and becomes part of the data-set.
5. The data is detokenized and the remote token service server.
6. The data is transmitted back to the local device.

Where and when should tokenization/encryption in this process in order to be compliant?